# How to custom Emmet Abbreviation in Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, syntax, sublimetext, emmet

I installed a new `Emmet Abbreviation` plugin in my *Sublime Text 3*, by default the Syntax Scopes **HTML** are respectively these:

**html**

```
<html></html>
```

**html:5** or **!**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

however i would like to add or edit such certain Syntax.
I already searched in *Preferences> Package Settings> Emmet> Settings*, but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redefine [`doc` snippet](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/snippets/html.json#L147). In Emmet, snippets are abbreviations itself, or, in other words, snippets are aliases to another abbreviations.

For customizing snippets in Sublime Text, see https://github.com/emmetio/sublime-text-plugin#adding-custom-emmet-snippets

Comment: And what to edit the html content? I mean `<! DOCTYPE html>....` have you been teaching in this documentation on GitHub?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can override any default Emmet snippet, including one that’s used to output DOCTYPE (which is `!!!`, as described in snippets file)